# Fragments not passing data

Tags: java, android

I read a lot of equal questions here in Stack, but (until now) had no luck. Am I missing something ? I need to fill this form and I'm doing Insert with Update, First screen is the insert and second (that isn't passing the data) is the update. I need the PK (CNPJ) for the update and didn't want for the user to put again.

I even put a set/get as a last resort for setText();

**Register_User_Fragment.class**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    name = getView().findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
    lastname = getView().findViewById(R.id.edt_lastname);
    email = getView().findViewById(R.id.edt_email);
    cnpj = getView().findViewById(R.id.edt_cnpj);
    cnpj.addTextChangedListener(CodeMask.mask(cnpj, CodeMask.FORMAT_CNPJ));
    razao = getView().findViewById(R.id.edt_razao);
    continue1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
    bd = new ManipulaDB(getActivity());

    continue1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String Name = name.getText().toString();
        String surname = lastname.getText().toString();
        String mail = email.getText().toString();
        String CNPJ = cnpj.getText().toString();
        String social = razao.getText().toString();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("CNPJ", CNPJ);
            ...

            else if (!bd.isDataPJ(CNPJ)) {
            registerUser(name, surname, mail, CNPJ, social, "null", "null", "null");
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fr = new Register_Region_Fragment();
            fr.setArguments(bundle);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_user, new Register_Region_Fragment());
            transaction.commit();
```

**Register_Region_Fragment.class**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container != null) {
        container.removeAllViews();
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container_region, container, false);
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String enterprise = bundle.getString("CNPJ");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "It works !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setEnterprise(enterprise);
    }
}
  @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    cnpj = getView().findViewById(R.id.edt_empresa);
    cnpj.addTextChangedListener(CodeMask.mask(cnpj, CodeMask.FORMAT_CNPJ));
    cnpj.setText(getEnterprise());
    ...
  continue2.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
        String CNPJ = cnpj.getText().toString();
        String vol = volume.getText().toString();
        String reg = regiao.getText().toString();
        String cat = categoria.getText().toString();

        else if (!bd.isDataPJ(CNPJ)){
            updateUser(CNPJ, vol, reg, cat);
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_region, new Register_Fragment_Login());
            transaction.commit();
        }

    });

        public void setEnterprise(String enterprise) {
         this.enterprise = enterprise;
    }

        public String getEnterprise () {
           return enterprise;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these few lines are the issue

```
 fr = new Register_Region_Fragment();
            fr.setArguments(bundle);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_user, new Register_Region_Fragment());
            transaction.commit();
```

You are creating a new Registration Fragment at line

```
 fr = new Register_Region_Fragment();
```

and set the bundle on the fr reference. (so far so good)

BUT here at this line

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_user, new Register_Region_Fragment());
```

you are creating a new instance of the Region Fragment which does not have any arguments.

You will need to use the `fr` reference with `transaction.replace.`